# throw new Exception in a test

Tags: c#, exception, testing, fitnesse

While browsing the code of my application I faced this:

```
private string[] ReadFromFile(string path)
{
    string[] data = null;
    try
    {
        data = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("The file is not correct");
    }

    return data;
}
```

Ok so I know this code is not good and I was about to refactor this. However, this code is used in the definition of some tests for FitNesse. This code is **never** used in production. The parameter given in this method *is supposed to be* always correct. So I feel like removing the whole try/catch block and let it crash if it should. FitNesse would give us the whole details about the exception thrown, but since it's a test fixture I'm wondering if it may be *ok*.

`File.ReadAllLines` can throw a dozen of different exceptions.

So my question: Is it acceptable to have such kind of code, outside production, even if used to test production code, and in a environment under control? Or is it bad under any circumstances?

Comment: I do not know fitnesse, but if it catches and logs the actual exception i wouldn't throw (redefine) a new exception

Comment: If you really want to throw your own exception, pass the original exception as inner exception. This will be really helpful for finding the real error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is even worse to have such code in unit tests than having it in production code. In production code sometimes it might make a sense to hide some exception details (though they still should be delivered via `InnerException` for example) but in unit tests you should always see as much as possible because they are done for **you** (developer, not end user). So I think this entire try/catch block should be removed.

Also if in some other case you would like to fail test then I would recommend using `Assert.Fail("message")` construction since it makes it more clear then tests should be treated as failed if it reached this point. Not sure whether it can be applied to FitNesse though.

Comment: Agreed. Do not have such code anywhere, let alone in a Unit Test!

Comment: Well FitNesse is more about functionnal testing than unit testing. For a unit test I wouldn't have hesitated. In my case it's not this feature that is tested but this feature is used in a test (the actual test is about verifying some processing of the data retrieved with this method)

Answer (score 1):

I would catch it, and then throw a streamlined exception that will leverage the functionality of FitNesse

```
private string[] ReadFromFile(string path)
{
    string[] data = null;
    try
    {
        data = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("message:<<Problem reading in file: " +e.getMessage() + ">>");
    }

    return data;
}
```

If you do this, the error message will appear in context and be easier to identify.  Unfortunately, an unwrapped exception will appear in a exception block separate from the fixture that had the problem.  The e.printStackTrace() will give you information on the output page that can give you more details.

I agree with others that in unit test code you want the exception to occur in context of the code.  However your audience is different when in a unit test.  The people working with it should always be developers.  In the case of FitNesse tests, you are working with BAs and Testers, who may benefit from a little extra diagnostics.

The code I added is Java, and I know this is a c# test, but the spirit is the same and the "message:<< exception" should work the same in FitSharp for slim.  I work in Java and ruby, so my c# is really weak.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch exception you should do something with it, write logs e.g. If you only throw your own exception you lose stack trace of a last exception.